# Why do I get an undefined scope.ngModel on an angularJS directive's link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angularJS directive for a masked input, that when a certain condition is met, I want to remove the mask.
I was getting errors for the scope.ngModel being undefined in the code, however when I did a console.log(scope.ngModel) I was getting a value.
I decided to put in a watch and surprisingly it seems that the ngModel goes through several assignment iterations before getting the actual model value.

This is my directive code:

```
    angular.module('app').directive('maskedtext', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            field: '=',
            ngModel: '=',
            miscTables: '='
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/maskedInputTemplate.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var strfld = scope.field.UseMaskField;
            var searchvals = scope.field.UseMaskValues;
            console.log(scope.ngModel); //***LINE 20***
            if (strfld != null && searchvals != null) {
                scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    console.log(scope.ngModel); //***LINE 23***
                    if (newVal != oldVal) {
                        var dbval = newVal[strfld];
                        var arrvals = searchvals.split(",");
                        var i = arrvals.indexOf(dbval);
                        if (i < 0) {
                            attrs["ui-mask"] = "";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And the console results are:

```
LINE 20: undefined
LINE 23: undefined
LINE 23: undefined
LINE 23: Object {Guest_no: 82000001, Parent_no: 82000001, Salute: "", Suffix: ""...}
```

As you can see, within the watch my ngModel get the value expected on the 3rd iteration.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Or how can I access the ngModel without using a watch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Angular runs a digest, it will execute the `$watch` event multiple times.  That's why you're seeing it run so many times.  The best way to ignore the irrelevant events is to compare the `newVal` and `oldVal`:

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal == undefined || angular.equals(newVal, oldVal)) return;

    // ... if values are different, process the $watch event ...
}
```

However, to actually fix your problem, you can ignore the `$watch` and just access the `ng-model` in a different way:

```
if (attrs.ngModel) {
    var MyModel = scope[attrs.ngModel];
}
```

Use `MyModel` to access your `ng-model`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Although I still get undefined with the var MyModel = scope[attrs.ngModel]; Thoughts?